# What does "This won’t go to Harbor" mean?

Tags: den-of-thieves

Right at the end of the film after the firefight, one cop says to 'Big Nick' O'Brien - “This won’t go to Harbor”

What does this dialog mean?

Still from DVD… Timestamp 2:15:52

[image]

Comment: I found the dialog here: https://www.scripts.com/script.php?id=den_of_thieves_6715&p=28

Comment: Interesting that Harbor is like a proper noun - like a name.  Could not be accurate however.

Comment: Found it, added still + subs from DVD. Name isn't mentioned anywhere else in the script or cast list. Subs are DVD picture-based so I can't text-search them.

Comment: My only guess is that he is saying that the dead cop’s wife is not going to let this rest - it’s not going to be easy for Nick - it ‘won’t go to harbor’ - but carry on being in a storm. It’s just such a strange place to use the metaphor, and it feels a bit too literary for the character and the scene.  I thought maybe it’s an LA thing or a police thing. Despite the subtitles upper case, it could be just because the subtitle editor didn’t understand it either? I wonder  how it’s been dubbed.

Comment: My first thought was that it was going to be a mondegreen - I was kind of surprised it wasn't. ;)

Comment: Foreign subs also say 'Harbor' as though it was a proper name, eg Irá a Harbor in Spanish, although my abysmal comprehension of Spanish would think that is 'will go to Harbor'. I'm no wiser ;)

Comment: I found one other clip where someone talks about going to "Harbor," but I think they're talking about a high school: https://www.getyarn.io/yarn-clip/dfb18ef6-e911-4e3f-a2b4-7a10337d8529

Comment: Harbor is a region of LA with a school and hospital - but I’m not sure how the context works?

Comment: Hmmm… that's something that really requires local knowledge;) Could be it. Scriptwriter assumed everyone in the world would know that… something they always do the complete opposite of when filming outside the US… where they'll always caption it London, England, for example, with a backdrop of the Houses of Parliament, like there could be another confusingly similar London, maybe in Uruguay  ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin, haha so in the sequel let’s see someone standing over a thief saying “This won’t be returning to the scrubs”.

Comment: The script on Script Slugs makes no mention of Harbor, Harbour or even the word "won't" in any context to this scene.

Comment: @Tetsujin - London, Ontario.  Although no one would reference that city in a movie.  :-)

Comment: Sure - there are also 17 Londons in the US, apparently ;)

Comment: https://dhs.lacounty.gov/harbor-ucla-medical-center/

Answer (score 2):

Borracho has just been killed. He's just said that he's going to call Borracho's wife. One thing he could mean is that the task of informing Borracho's wife is not going to go to "Harbor" (the hospital).

(But, really, I hear "[I'm] gonna go to Harbor," which would be a much more understandable line there, if Harbor indeed means the hospital.)